# adding columns based on ordering and grouping

Tags: r, dplyr

I have this data frame

```
dat = data.frame(ID= c(1,1,1,2,3,3),
              NumberInSequence= c(1,2,3,1,1,2),
              StartTime = as.POSIXct(c("2016-01-01 05:52:05 GMT","2016-01-01 05:52:11 GMT","2016-01-01 05:52:16 GMT","2016-01-01 05:40:05 GMT","2016-01-01 06:12:13 GMT","2016-01-01 07:12:26 GMT"))  ,
              EndTime = as.POSIXct(c("2016-01-01 05:52:10 GMT","2016-01-01 05:52:16 GMT","2016-01-01 05:52:30 GMT","2016-01-01 05:46:05 GMT","2016-01-01 06:12:25 GMT","2016-01-01 08:00:00 GMT")  )
               )


dat

  ID NumberInSequence           StartTime             EndTime
1  1                1 2016-01-01 05:52:05 2016-01-01 05:52:10
2  1                2 2016-01-01 05:52:11 2016-01-01 05:52:16
3  1                3 2016-01-01 05:52:16 2016-01-01 05:52:30
4  2                1 2016-01-01 05:40:05 2016-01-01 05:46:05
5  3                1 2016-01-01 06:12:13 2016-01-01 06:12:25
6  3                2 2016-01-01 07:12:26 2016-01-01 08:00:00
```

Each ID can have 1 or more rows and each row is in time order for every ID.  I'd like to add 2 columns:

1st column: "Duration" which the length of time, in seconds, BETWEEN the EndTime of an ID to the next start time of the same id.

2nd column:  "Next start time" which is the actual next start time of the same ID.

So the results should look like this:

dat$Duration = ?

dat$NextStartTime = ?

```
  ID NumberInSequence           StartTime             EndTime   Duration    NextStartTime
1  1                1 2016-01-01 05:52:05 2016-01-01 05:52:10     1     2016-01-01 05:52:11
2  1                2 2016-01-01 05:52:11 2016-01-01 05:52:16     0     2016-01-01 05:52:16
3  1                3 2016-01-01 05:52:16 2016-01-01 05:52:30     NA     NA
4  2                1 2016-01-01 05:40:05 2016-01-01 05:46:05     NA     NA
5  3                1 2016-01-01 06:12:13 2016-01-01 06:12:25     3601    2016-01-01 07:12:26
6  3                2 2016-01-01 07:12:26 2016-01-01 08:00:00     NA     NA
```

For example for ID = 3 a NUMBER IN SEQUENCE = 1 the end time is 61 seconds later so the duration is 61 and the next start time is 07:12:26 from ID = 3 and number in sequence = 2.

For rows where there is there is no next start time NA should appear like ID = 2 and number in sequence = 1.

I was looking at doing this with dplyr somehow....

######## UPDATE

lead() is the answer but there is a minor issue. Please see this post

[using dplyr lead but with some contraints](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39714029/using-dplyr-lead-but-with-some-contraints)

Comment: `dat %>% group_by(ID) %>% mutate(NextStartTime = lead(StartTime), duration = difftime(NextStartTime, EndTime, units = 's'))` maybe

Comment: Thank you can you take a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39714029/using-dplyr-lead-but-with-some-contraints

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `NextStartTime`, as long as your data is in order (use `arrange(ID, NumberInSequence)` if unsure), you can use `dplyr::lead`, which is like `stats::lag` on a time series with a negative lag.

For `Duration`, you can subtract times, but if the units can be on different units of magnitude, it's safer to use `difftime` directly so you can keep consistent units.

All together:

```
library(dplyr)

dat %>% group_by(ID) %>% 
    arrange(ID, NumberInSequence) %>%    # not necessary if already arranged, as here
    mutate(NextStartTime = lead(StartTime), 
           Duration = difftime(NextStartTime, EndTime, units = 's'))

## Source: local data frame [6 x 6]
## Groups: ID [3]
## 
##      ID NumberInSequence           StartTime             EndTime       NextStartTime  Duration
##   <dbl>            <dbl>              <dttm>              <dttm>              <dttm>    <time>
## 1     1                1 2016-01-01 05:52:05 2016-01-01 05:52:10 2016-01-01 05:52:11    1 secs
## 2     1                2 2016-01-01 05:52:11 2016-01-01 05:52:16 2016-01-01 05:52:16    0 secs
## 3     1                3 2016-01-01 05:52:16 2016-01-01 05:52:30                <NA>   NA secs
## 4     2                1 2016-01-01 05:40:05 2016-01-01 05:46:05                <NA>   NA secs
## 5     3                1 2016-01-01 06:12:13 2016-01-01 06:12:25 2016-01-01 07:12:26 3601 secs
## 6     3                2 2016-01-01 07:12:26 2016-01-01 08:00:00                <NA>   NA secs
```

Comment: Hi @alistaire this almost works completly. Can you take a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39714029/using-dplyr-lead-but-with-some-contraints