# using dplyr lead but with some contraints

Tags: r, dplyr

I have this data frame, dat, and dplyr is used to add the "NextStatTime" field which is the start time after the End time for an ID and "Duration" which is the time from the End Time to the next start time for an ID.

The data looks like this:

```
     dat = data.frame(ID= c(1,1,1,2,3,3),
                      NumberInSequence= c(1,3,4,1,1,2),
                      StartTime = as.POSIXct(c("2016-01-01 05:52:05 GMT","2016-01-01 05:52:11 GMT","2016-01-01 05:52:16 GMT","2016-01-01 05:40:05 GMT","2016-01-01 06:12:13 GMT","2016-01-01 07:12:26 GMT"))  ,
                      EndTime = as.POSIXct(c("2016-01-01 05:52:10 GMT","2016-01-01 05:52:16 GMT","2016-01-01 05:52:30 GMT","2016-01-01 05:46:05 GMT","2016-01-01 06:12:25 GMT","2016-01-01 08:00:00 GMT")  )
                       )

    dat
    dat %>% group_by(ID) %>% mutate(NextStartTime = lead(StartTime), duration = as.numeric(difftime(NextStartTime, EndTime, units = 's')))

  ID NumberInSequence           StartTime             EndTime       NextStartTime duration
  <dbl>            <dbl>              <time>              <time>              <time>    <dbl>
1     1                1 2016-01-01 05:52:05 2016-01-01 05:52:10 2016-01-01 05:52:11        1
2     1                3 2016-01-01 05:52:11 2016-01-01 05:52:16 2016-01-01 05:52:16        0
3     1                4 2016-01-01 05:52:16 2016-01-01 05:52:30                <NA>       NA
4     2                1 2016-01-01 05:40:05 2016-01-01 05:46:05                <NA>       NA
5     3                1 2016-01-01 06:12:13 2016-01-01 06:12:25 2016-01-01 07:12:26     3601
6     3                2 2016-01-01 07:12:26 2016-01-01 08:00:00                <NA>       NA
```

That is very close to the right answer but if there is a missing ID it still calculates and is misleading.

For example - look at ID= 1 there are 3 entries with sequence numbers 1,3 and 4. There is no #2 in the sequence. It is missing so the NextStartTime and Duration for ID = 1 and Number in sequence = 1 should be NA NOT  05:52:11  and 1.

Is there a way to impose this logic?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two options:

---

#### `tidyr::complete`

One option is to use `tidyr::complete` to fill in the missing rows, and use the previous method.

*Downside*: You get new mostly `NA` rows added. You could omit them after the fact with a careful `filter` call, though.
*Upside*: It's easy to write and understand, and preserves the original logic.

```
library(tidyverse)

dat %>% group_by(ID) %>% 
    complete(NumberInSequence = seq(max(NumberInSequence))) %>% 
    mutate(NextStartTime = lead(StartTime), 
           Duration = as.numeric(difftime(NextStartTime, EndTime, units = 's')))

## Source: local data frame [7 x 6]
## Groups: ID [3]
## 
##      ID NumberInSequence           StartTime             EndTime       NextStartTime Duration
##   <dbl>            <dbl>              <dttm>              <dttm>              <dttm>    <dbl>
## 1     1                1 2016-01-01 05:52:05 2016-01-01 05:52:10                <NA>       NA
## 2     1                2                <NA>                <NA> 2016-01-01 05:52:11       NA
## 3     1                3 2016-01-01 05:52:11 2016-01-01 05:52:16 2016-01-01 05:52:16        0
## 4     1                4 2016-01-01 05:52:16 2016-01-01 05:52:30                <NA>       NA
## 5     2                1 2016-01-01 05:40:05 2016-01-01 05:46:05                <NA>       NA
## 6     3                1 2016-01-01 06:12:13 2016-01-01 06:12:25 2016-01-01 07:12:26     3601
## 7     3                2 2016-01-01 07:12:26 2016-01-01 08:00:00                <NA>       NA
```

---

#### subset `lead(StartTime)` with `ifelse`

`ifelse` inconveniently strips attributes, so you can't do `ifelse(lead(StartTime) == NumberInSequence + 1, lead(StartTime), NA)` without reconverting the resulting integer back to POSIXct, which is a hassle. Instead, it's easier to subset with `ifelse`, passing an `NA` if it's not a match, so the vector indexed returns `NA` instead of nothing.

*Downside*: It's finicky to write in order to keep types.
*Upside*: No additional rows are added.

```
dat %>% group_by(ID) %>% 
    mutate(NextStartTime = lead(StartTime)[ifelse(lead(NumberInSequence) == (NumberInSequence + 1), TRUE, NA)], 
           duration = difftime(NextStartTime, EndTime, units = 's'))

## Source: local data frame [6 x 6]
## Groups: ID [3]
## 
##      ID NumberInSequence           StartTime             EndTime       NextStartTime  duration
##   <dbl>            <dbl>              <dttm>              <dttm>              <dttm>    <time>
## 1     1                1 2016-01-01 05:52:05 2016-01-01 05:52:10                <NA>   NA secs
## 2     1                3 2016-01-01 05:52:11 2016-01-01 05:52:16 2016-01-01 05:52:16    0 secs
## 3     1                4 2016-01-01 05:52:16 2016-01-01 05:52:30                <NA>   NA secs
## 4     2                1 2016-01-01 05:40:05 2016-01-01 05:46:05                <NA>   NA secs
## 5     3                1 2016-01-01 06:12:13 2016-01-01 06:12:25 2016-01-01 07:12:26 3601 secs
## 6     3                2 2016-01-01 07:12:26 2016-01-01 08:00:00                <NA>   NA secs
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd like to leave an alternative way using `POSIXct`. You can avoid the numeric-to-date conversion in the following way. If you use `if_else()` in the dplyr package, it cares about class. What you want to do is to keep the `POSIXct` class in the function. If you type `typeof(dat$StartTime)`, you will realize that `StartTime` is in double. Its class is POSIXct. So you want to use `NA_real_` and treat the NAs as POSIXct. Please make sure that you provide origin and your time zone. In my case, I needed to specify my time zone as "Asia/Tokyo" in order or produce the expected outcome.

```
library(dplyr)
group_by(dat, ID) %>%
mutate(NextStartTime = if_else(abs(NumberInSequence - lead(NumberInSequence)) != 1,
                               true = as.POSIXct(NA_real_, origin = "1970-01-01 00:00:00", tz = "Asia/Tokyo"),
                               false = lead(StartTime)),
       Duration = difftime(NextStartTime, EndTime, unit = "s"))


#     ID NumberInSequence           StartTime             EndTime       NextStartTime  Duration
#  <dbl>            <dbl>              <dttm>              <dttm>              <dttm>    <time>
#1     1                1 2016-01-01 05:52:05 2016-01-01 05:52:10                <NA>   NA secs
#2     1                3 2016-01-01 05:52:11 2016-01-01 05:52:16 2016-01-01 05:52:16    0 secs
#3     1                4 2016-01-01 05:52:16 2016-01-01 05:52:30                <NA>   NA secs
#4     2                1 2016-01-01 05:40:05 2016-01-01 05:46:05                <NA>   NA secs
#5     3                1 2016-01-01 06:12:13 2016-01-01 06:12:25 2016-01-01 07:12:26 3601 secs
#6     3                2 2016-01-01 07:12:26 2016-01-01 08:00:00                <NA>   NA secs
```